# Como restringir que el usuario solo cargue archivos de Excel o de hojas de calculo (.xls, .xlsx,)en general. en Genexus 16

Tags: excel, genexus, upload, type, carga

Buenas tardes a todos y como puedo hacer para que el explorador solo me muestre los archivo con extensión .xlsx o archivos de excel en general. Por que actualmente me permite seleccionar cualquier archivo y manda error, lo que quiero no es corregir el error, si no dos cosas, una, que el explorador solo muestre archivos excel o dos, que cuando seleccione otro tipo de archivo, muestre un mensaje al usuario.

intente con la siguiente línea, pero no funcionó.

&extension=&file.FileType
If &extension=xlsx
contunia
else
msg('error en el tipo de archivo')
endif

De antemano gracas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre que puedes resolverlo con el control "File Upload".

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30574,File%20Upload%20control

En el mismo puedes por la propiedad "Accepted File Type", indicar que extensión quieres para los archivos. En tu caso debería ser así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya lo estoy proando, muchas gracias Marce!

Comment: Hola Marce, ya use el UC Fileupload, pero ahora como puedo utilizar el archivo de excel? Anteriormente con tenía una variable tipo blob (&file), en esta seleccionaba el archivo. Después ocupaba la variable &excel de tipo ExcelDocument. Entonces solo hacia lo siguiente &excel.Open(&file) y listo podía ocupar o cargar la información que trae el archivo de excel. Pero ahora con el FileUpload no encuentro como

Answer (score 0):

La única opción para que la ventana de selección muestre determinados tipos de archivos es como dijo el colega de la respuesta anterior, utilizando el UC FileUpload..

Verificar la extensión del archivo, es algo que hice muchas veces ..
En el ejemplo pusiste una variable file... Pero como asignaste el source?

Debes tener cuidado en la forma en la que tomas el archivo, es decir... A través de que...
Usas en pantalla una variable blob ? O blobfile? Cuidado con esto porque los métodos de nombre y extensión no devuelven lo mismo...
Una vez hice un ejemplo para compararlos y son distintos...

Comment: Hola Eduardo de antemano gracias. Así es, es de tipo blob. No sabía eso que comentas, pero lo voy a tomar en cuenta. Y sí ya voy a empezar probar la opción del Fileupload, como me comentan. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, ya use el UC Fileupload, pero ahora como puedo utilizar el archivo de excel? Anteriormente con tenía una variable tipo blob (&file), en esta seleccionaba el archivo. Después ocupaba la variable &excel de tipo ExcelDocument.  Entonces solo hacia lo siguiente &excel.Open(&file) y listo podía ocupar o cargar la información que trae el archivo de excel. Pero ahora con el FileUpload no encuentro como.

Comment: Hola Omar...   lo puede hacer de la misma forma... cada archivo de ese UC es tambien del tipo blob..

podes hacer lo siguiente:
For &FileUploadData in &UploadedFiles
 &ExcelDocument.Open(&FileUploadData.File) 
...
...
...

Comment: Listo ya quedó Eduardo, gracias.